# Scala - unescape Unicode String without Apache

Tags: scala, unicode

I have a String "b\u00f4lovar" and i was wondering if it's possible to unescape without use Commons-lang. It works but i'm facing a problem on some enviroments and i would like to minimize it (i.e.: it works on my machine but not works on production).

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(variables.getOrElse("name", ""))
```

How can i unescape it without apache lib?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Write  your own routine to parse the hex digits and make a character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Only Unicode escapes

If you want to unescape *only* sequences in the format `\u0000` than it is simple to do it with a single regex replace:

```
def unescapeUnicode(str: String): String =
  """\\u+([0-9a-fA-F]{4})""".r.replaceAllIn(str,
    m => Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16).toChar match {
      case '\\' => """\\"""
      case '$' => """\$"""
      case c => c.toString
    })
```

And the result is

```
scala> unescapeUnicode("b\\u00f4lovar \\u30B7")
res1: String = bôlovar シ
```

We have to process characters `$` and `\` separately, because they are treated as special by the `java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement` method:

```
def wrongUnescape(str: String): String =
  """\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})""".r.replaceAllIn(str,
    m => Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16).toChar.toString)

scala> wrongUnescape("\\u00" + Integer.toString('$', 16))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference: group index is missing
  at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:819)
  ... 46 elided

scala> wrongUnescape("\\u00" + Integer.toString('\\', 16))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing
   at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:809)
   ... 46 elided
```

### All escape characters

Unicode character escapes are a bit special: they are not a part of string literals, but a part of the program code. There is a separate phase to replace unicode escapes with characters:

```
scala> Integer.toString('a', 16)
res2: String = 61

scala> val \u0061 = "foo"
a: String = foo

scala> // first \u005c is replaced with a backslash, and then \t is replaced with a tab.
scala> "\u005ct"
res3: String = "    "
```

There is a function `StringContext.treatEscapes` in Scala library, that supports all [normal escapes](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/01-lexical-syntax.html#escape-sequences) from the language specification.

So if you want to support unicode escapes and all normal Scala escapes, you can unescape both sequentially:

```
def unescape(str: String): String =
  StringContext.treatEscapes(unescapeUnicode(str))

scala> unescape("\\u0061\\n\\u0062")
res4: String =
a
b

scala> unescape("\\u005ct")
res5: String = "    "
```