# how to convert charCode to uncode in scala

Tags: scala, unicode

I am trying to convert string `\u8fc8` to "迈" in scala. The string `\u8fc8` is stored as six chars which are '\', 'u', '8', 'f', 'c', '8'.

In Python I can do this:

```
print("\u8fc8".decode("unicode-escape"))
```

It prints "迈", but I could not find a way to make that happen in Scala, can any body help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"\u8fc8".format("unicode-escape")`

Check this in ScalaFiddle: [how to convert charCode to uncode in scala](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/pUn6H1z/0)

For "\u8fc8" it is a bit more complex, with the answer of [scala-unescape-unicode-string-without-apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685845/scala-unescape-unicode-string-without-apache?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa):

```
def unescapeUnicode(str: String): String = 
  """\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})""".r.replaceAllIn(str, 
    m => Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16).toChar.toString)
```

unescapeUnicode("\u8fc8")

Check the updated ScalaFiddle: [how to convert charCode to uncode in scala](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/pUn6H1z/0)

Comment: I tried, but it doest work, '\' is an escape string, when you write it in the code, you should write "\\u8fc8"

Comment: I converted "8fc8" to 36808, but I don't know how to create a unicode with this integer in Scala

Comment: have you checked the ScalaFiddle? https://scalafiddle.io/sf/pUn6H1z/0 - here "迈" is printed.

Comment: yes, it prints "迈" in ScalaFiddle, but it didn't work in my original code, it reads data from a file, so the '\' is escaped

Comment: ah ok - please add then the String that you get from the file to your question.

Comment: just "\\u8fc8", but it prints "\u8fc8"

Comment: I know that in JavaScript, I can run `String.fromCharCode(36808)` to get "迈", but I don't know how to do this in Scala