# Pass delimiter to Spark as an argument

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to pass a value to my Spark program which would be used as a delimiter to read a .dat file. My code looks something like this

```
val delim = args(0)
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", delim).load("/path/to/file/")
```

And I run the program as following command -

```
spark2-submit --class a.b.c.MyClass My.jar \\u0001
```

But I get an error saying that multiple characters can't be used as delimiter. But when I directly use the String instead of getting it as a variable, the code works fine

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", "\u0001").load("/path/to/file/")
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: please check if the following thread helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928999/passing-command-line-arguments-to-spark-shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String `"\u0001"` is a unicode character, but what is passed to spark from the command line is a literal string `"\\u0001"`. You need to explicitly unescape Unicode:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", unescapeUnicode(delim)).load("/path/to/file/")
```

Find `unescapeUnicode` function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29686933/2890093).